# ruby keep_if comparison of an array with string

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am trying to compare a string with an array of objects. So that when a string value matches that object within the array it will keep it.

Here is the example:

```
sample = [#<Model::ID:0x007fcb83ace8a0
  type_id: 6,
  parent_name: "Old Man",
  child_name: "Junior">,
 #<Model::ID:0x007fcb83abd0a0
  type_id: 6,
  parent_name: "Mary",
  child_name: "Michelle">,
 #<Model::ID:0x007fcb83abce70
  type_id: 6,
  parent_name: "Ole Bob",
  child_name: "Bobby">]

name = "Michelle"
```

So I tried the following:

```
sample.keep_if { |keep_ele| [keep_ele]["child_name"] == name }
```

and this returns the following error:
TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer

But when I'm in IRB and I output `sample[1]["child_name"]` it equals `"Michelle"`

So then I tried:

```
sample.keep_if { |keep_ele| keep_ele["child_name"] == name }
```

and it just returned an empty array: `[]`

Any idea on how to run the keep_if?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`keep_ele` inside the `keep_if` block is already a model object (item) from the array. You should use the following comparison instead:

```
sample.keep_if { |keep_ele| keep_ele["child_name"] == name }
```

Take a look at the documentation page for [`Array#keep_if`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-keep_if). Here is similar example:

```
sample = [
  {
    "child_name" => "Mike"
  }, {
    "child_name" => "Michelle"
  }, {
    "child_name" => "Joe"
  }
]

name = "Michelle"
puts sample.keep_if { |keep_ele| keep_ele["child_name"] == name }
# => {"child_name"=>"Michelle"}
```